# I do not know what cookie Idea-f5324dcc=41f745e2-43a5-4a7f-8e31-1b35896e1ac6 represent

Tags: java, google-chrome, http, web, spring-security

I just use spring security to create my web application.

When I input the url /welcome to get my welcome page which do not need user to be authenticated, my request Headers will have: **Cookie: Idea-f5324dcc=41f745e2-43a5-4a7f-8e31-1b35896e1ac6**.Once I login in, my request Headers will have: **Idea-f5324dcc=41f745e2-43a5-4a7f-8e31-1b35896e1ac6; JSESSIONID=EE2933C4E8BD0FDFDD61CAA8CD65B806**.
The cookie **Idea-f5324dcc=41f745e2-43a5-4a7f-8e31-1b35896e1ac6** will always exists across all http requests.

I know the cookie **JSESSIONID=EE2933C4E8BD0FDFDD61CAA8CD65B806** represent the session for current user,but what is Idea-f5324dcc=41f745e2-43a5-4a7f-8e31-1b35896e1ac6?

Comment: Delete that cookie in your web browser and check when it re-appears. It could be possible that this cookie comes from a  public web site rather than from your own web application.

Comment: @Stefan: Cookies are only sent back to the same domain that set them.

Comment: @Stefan.Ok, thank you for your advice.After I deleted that cookie according to your advice, it never appeared again.It seems to be from other website?